# stop background image from repeating

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing an app and I'm having trouble with some javascript that's causing the icon in the mobile nav bar to repeat.

Here's my javascript I'm running on page load:

```
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css(
    'background-image',
    'url("'+Tiggzi.getImagePath('75-phone.png')+'")'
);
```

**I've tried this with no luck:**

```
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css(
    'background-image',
    'url("'+Tiggzi.getImagePath('75-phone.png')+'")'
);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Please learn the difference between `Java` and `javascript` before you proceed.

Comment: Made code readable, try using 4 spaces at the beginning of lines which just hold code

Comment: Very rude sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: I think it is pretty rude to go slapping tags on posts without even bothering to read them.  -1 for your laziness.

Comment: It's not laziness. It's lack of knowledge. I'm doing the best I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `background-repeat` is hanging separately.  Enclose it similar what you've done for `background-image`.

```
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css('background-image', 'url("'+Tiggzi.getImagePath('75-phone.png')+'")');
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
```

or

```
 $('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url("'+Tiggzi.getImagePath('75-phone.png')+'")', 
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
});
```

Check this sample [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/gfWES/13/)

Comment: Just chain the `.css()`?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have updated my answer, is this you are referring?

Comment: Chaining would be `$().css(blah).css(blah2)`, but this option is better ;-)

Comment: What if I wanted this image centered horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

The [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) rule has to be separated from the other. So there has to bee two *different* jQuery's [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function calls.

```
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
$('a[dsid="nav_contact"]').css({
       'background-image' : 'url("'+Tiggzi.getImagePath('75-phone.png')+'")',                           
       'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'});
```